# delete element from table view objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a table view full of data defined from the user. the array is gathered from nsuserdefaults and is show in a table view controller. i am trying to implement a delete function. it looks fine but when i press delete the error comes

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

The code i have for Favourites.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FavoritesViewController: UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *favoriteItems;

@end
```

Then the piece where i initialize

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

favoriteItems= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favoritesArray"];
[self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

I feel like the above code is where the problem is. NSUserDefaults; I expect is an NSArray. So how do I change it too Mutable?

Just for interests sake the following sets up the delete method

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //remove the deleted object from your data source.
    //If your data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
    [self.favoriteItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoriteItems forKey:@"favoritesArray"];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // tell table to refresh now
  }
}
```

Really appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favoritesArray"]` is returning an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

The solution is to create a mutable copy of the array when you load it from `NSUserDefaults`:

`[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favoritesArray"] mutableCopy];`

This is one of the most confusing aspects of Objective-C's type system. You'd naturally think that if the system lets you assign something to an `NSMutableArray` variable, then it must be an `NSMutableArray` (in Swift, you'd be right). But there is *absolutely no guarantee* of this in ObjC - the syntax makes the language look like it's statically typed, but it isn't.